# Can I set a delay on startup programs that are shown on Windows 8 Task Manager?

Tags: windows, boot, task-manager, windows-8

Microsoft created a new feature on Windows 8 that allow users to manage startup programs on Windows Task Manager:

[image]

We can Disable or Enable programs that Windows show us that are having "High" impact on Windows 8 startup time. There is a way to disable it, but assuming that I don't want to completelly disable it from automatic startup, I just want to set a delay time on this program startup, as already happends on [Windows services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service):

> Automatic (Delayed) is a new startup type introduced in Windows Vista,
>   that starts the service a short while after the system has finished
>   its booting and initial busy operations, so that the system boots up
>   faster.

[image]

There is any way to do that? Even being with Windows register, vbs, powershell or whaterver..?

Comment: **correctly answered here** ... http://superuser.com/a/905326/401734

Comment: @JoeBlow  That adds a delay for **all** desktop apps.  Possibly even just the ones in the startup folder (shell:Startup).  No?  Say you want to delay a specific program, can that solution do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Soluto](https://www.soluto.com/boot-time) should do the trick - Its an application meant for measuring and optimising start up times. You can select the 'pause' option to load a startup item when needed, and the delay option to delay a startup entry.

This [article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-small-windows-freewares-delay-program-launch-startup/) seems to state its a registry hack, but dosen't actually say what entries need editing - so this may be another option.

Comment: I was really hoping to be able to do this with installing an application but I installed Soluto last night and it is pretty sweet.  Good call.

Comment: FYI, Soluto now seems to be an iOS/Android-only offering.

Comment: Fixed the link, they still have a pc version hidden away. This is why software rec questions suck sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

This article discusses ["3 Small Windows Tools To Delay any Program(s) At Startup"](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-small-windows-freewares-delay-program-launch-startup/).  The recommendations are:

1. [Startup Delayer](http://www.r2.com.au/page/products/show/startup-delayer/).  I found this to be a small but full featured program.  There are free and premium versions to choose from.
2. [LaunchLater](http://launchlater.codeplex.com/). Open source, but out of date (last updated Aug 30, 2011).  I didn't try this one.
3. [WinPatrol](http://www.winpatrol.com/).  Well-designed [`Autoruns`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)-like program. Frequently updated. Free and "Plus" versions.

Soluto is a strange cloud-/web-based solution, and it seems to require you to create an account.  Not on my list of programs to try.