# How to delay starting programs at Windows startup?

Tags: windows-10

I have the following in a batch file in `C:\Users\cat\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`:

```
sleep 30
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe
```

To start Steam with a 30 second delay, in place of just `Steam.lnk` that starts it right away.

This does not work, for Steam, or for other programs, with other time delays.

How do I delay startup applications with a script?

I'd rather not download another application to do this, like [this question](https://superuser.com/q/465019/513388) (which also suggests **many broken links** and non-FOSS programs) suggests.

Comment: Steam normally is set to auto start with windows. Have you disabled this feature? Otherwise the second instance will only trigger an "oh, steam is already running, I'll do nothing."

Comment: @LPChip Yes, I have disabled that to try to delay it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding delays to batchfiles is often problematic.

[Rob Vanderwoude](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/wait.php) has a good description of methods, and I've found the Ping method to be most reliable.

30 second delay:

```
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 30000 >NUL
```

If network isn't available immediately at boot and so the pings fail, then a more complex wait script (same website source) using Choice timing out should work:

```
CHOICE /C n /T 30 /D n /M "Wait 30 sec. To cancel hit:"
```

Comment: Doesn't that example require network? Why not 127.0.0.1?

Comment: yes, could be a problem straight at boot. Answer updated. I included 1.1.1.1 as that was the example on the page I referenced. No reason not to try 127.0.0.1.

Comment: The reason 1.1.1.1 is used is because it will timeout, creating a second delay. With -n x (count x times) you can somewhat set it to seconds too. 127.0.0.1 will always resolve, and as such a wait of 30000 is possibly not admired.